# WP7 How to parse the XML?

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

In wp7 i want to parse xml tag

.Xml :

```
<top>
<value name="Group A">
<team position="1" name="india" won="10" lose="5"/>
<team position="2" name="pakistan" won="5" lose="5"/>
</value>

<value name="Group B">
<team position="1" name="Aus" won="10" lose="5"/>
<team position="2" name="newzeland" won="5" lose="5"/>
</value>
</top>
```

i want output like this,

```
Group A

1  India 10  5
2  pak    5  10

Group B

1  Aus        5    5
2  Neszeland  5   5
```

I' m using parser like this,

```
 list = (from story in xmlTweets.Descendants("value")

                             select new ViewModel
                             {
                                 group= story.Attribute("name").Value,

                             }).ToList();

list1 = (from story in xmlTweets.Descendants("team")

                             select new ViewModel
                             {
                                 position= story.Attribute("position").Value,
name= story.Attribute("name").Value,
won= story.Attribute("won").Value,
lose= story.Attribute("lose").Value,

                             }).ToList();
```

output:

```
Group A

Group B

1  India 10  5
2  pak    5  10

1  Aus        5    5
2  Neszeland  5   5
```

Please tell me some idea to do this.

thanks.

Comment: Your desired output looks like your actual output to me... what's wrong?

Comment: @Jon, his output is missing the grouping mechanism.

Comment: @Jon grouping are printed first after printing list . i want group and list.

Comment: @MagnusJohansson: Ah yes, I see now...

Comment: @Jon if you know this tell me some idea to do this.

Comment: @Jeeva: Give me a chance - I was writing an answer :) You'll need to restructure your view-model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you've got two separate lists - one for groups and one for teams. It looks to me like your view model needs to be richer - something like:

```
list = xml.Descendants("value")
          .Select(group => new GroupViewModel
          {
              Group = (string) group.Attribute("name"),
              Results = group.Elements("team")
                             .Select(team => new TeamViewModel
                             {
                                 Position = (int) team.Attribute("position"),
                                 Name = (string) team.Attribute("name"),
                                 Won = (int) team.Attribute("won"),
                                 Lost = (int) team.Attribute("lose")
                             })
                             .ToList()
          })
          .ToList();
```

Comment: what is Results? it is string or list?

Comment: @Jeeva: It's a list of TeamViewModel references (note the ToList method) which should be within your view model. You haven't said anything about how you're displaying these results, which makes it hard to give anything more concrete than this...

Comment: coming this error  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ViewModel>' to 'string'